# Just lost a million blocks after downloading Mist

Tags: mist

Any idea why, after downloading Mist, I lost ~1mio blocks as the lead block. Was at 3.2mio when I was syncing (at 2264479) and now, after firing up Mist, it shows best block at ~2.3mio. Any thoughts, answers for my issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated (and sorry about the vernacular). Cheers.

Comment: _"Was at 3.2mio when I was syncing (at 2264479)..."_ - Can you clarify this part? Are you sure it wasn't saying you were currently syncing block 2264479 (i.e. 2.3mio) of 3.2mio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to happen from time to time on Mist.  The block number it happens to be displaying is not always accurate. It's likely just a graphical error.

Comment: Thanks....In that you are correct. All good now. Appreciate the help